# Where's the dupe in close review?

Tags: bug, review, closing, user-interface

In close reviews, a post flagged as a duplicate and the claimed duplicate target are rendered as tabbed pages so that reviewer can compare them *without* leaving the page.  However, the tabbed pane is missing in [this close review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1151942).

[image: close review dupe target missing]

What's the cause of that?

My try:

The [auto-generated dupe comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3098648/#comment6386546_3098648) has a score of two.  However, when the "Close" dialog *doesn't* display the dupe target shown in the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After click "Close" in the "Close" dialog, it turns out that it's just a [review-audit](/questions/tagged/review-audit).  From this, one can conclude that **in a [review-audit](/questions/tagged/review-audit), a review target flagged as a duplicate *won't* have the "Duplicate" tabbed pane.**  In this case, this conclusion helps the reviewer know *a priori* that the review is actually a [review-audit](/questions/tagged/review-audit).