# Question Score Mismatch in Close Review

Tags: discussion, review, review-audit

I've just ran into a question during [this Close review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1159319).

[image: zero score]

When I clicked the question score, I saw it has five upvotes with zero downvotes.

[image: five upvotes]

What's the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my [previous review experience](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29784/290189), it seems that such **unexpected behaviour shows that it's a [review-audit](/questions/tagged/review-audit)**.  Therefore, the right thing to do is to click "Leave Open".

[image: review audit passed]

Comment: Just because the item is a review audit does not necessarily mean that the correct response to it is "Leave Open."

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche You're right.  I should have put "in this case" to be clear.